# Where to store user info after being logged in: React JS

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, session, cookies

I am using express-sessions, cookies, and React, to build a login system. Currently, once the user is logged in, they are allowed to make requests to certain routes, but if they're not, they're not allowed to.

However, my question is where I should store the user's username. Would storing it in localstorage cause security issues? Or is that a safe way to store something like a username?

The reason I'm not storing it in a cookie is because the cookie is httpOnly. Is this a good idea? All I'm storing in the cookie will be the user's username, so I'm not sure if I'm overdoing security, and I can just access the user's username from my frontend by having the cookie not being httpOnly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are also using `passport.js`, once the login is successful, you can make the backend send the response containing related user info. (but not sensitive information such as passwords)

I see no problem with storing usernames in cookies. It is displayed in the end anyway.

In terms of security, there is always a trade-off.

So, in the end, it depends on what is acceptable and safe for you.

[image: TRIANGLE]